# Extreme tall elements glitch

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

I try to make infinity scroll table with only currently visible items rendered in HTML. But with some millions of entries I encountered glich in rendering **extreme tall placeholders** for unloaded data.

I tried this with div elements and HTML tables too but with similiar glitch.

**Please use Chrome to reproduce the problem.** With Firefox is problem too but it behaves differently.

Here is minimal example code:
https://jsfiddle.net/bj0tmh2r/

```
<style>
 .row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f00 !important;
 }
</style>
<div class="table-responsive" style="max-height: 600px;">
        <div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md">123456</div>
                <div class="col-md">Row X</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md">123456</div>
                <div class="col-md">Row X</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md">123456</div>
                <div class="col-md">Row X</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="background: #f00;height: 33100000px;">

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md">123456</div>
                <div class="col-md">Row X</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md">123456</div>
                <div class="col-md">Row X</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md">123456</div>
                <div class="col-md">Row X</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md">123456</div>
                <div class="col-md">Row X</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md">123456</div>
                <div class="col-md">Row X</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="background: #0f0;height: 299px;">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you scroll to last .row elements, you can see **missing bottom red borders** between rows.

Why this happens. How to avoid it?